# How can I change the image click destination image src?

Tags: jquery, image, src, attr

I would like to change the src of each image when I click the image with J-Query. I want to change the src value using attr. I want to change it to 1_on.png when I click 1_off.png, and change it to 2_on.png when I click 2_off.png. I want to change it to off when I click the image and click it again. How can I do that?

```html
<img alt="" src="img/1_off.png" id="pic">
 <img alt="" src="img/2_off.png" id="pic">
 <img alt="" src="img/3_off.png" id="pic">
 <img alt="" src="img/4_off.png" id="pic">
 <img alt="" src="img/5_off.png" id="pic">
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Please also note that you can't have multiple elements with the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using below approach, But first change your id into class because there only one id with same in a single document. you your code would be like this.

```
<img alt="" src="img/1_off.png" class="pic" data-toggle="1_on.png" data-active="on" onclick="activate_toggle(this)">
<img alt="" src="img/2_off.png" class="pic" data-toggle="2_on.png" data-active="on" onclick="activate_togle(this)">
<img alt="" src="img/3_off.png" class="pic" data-toggle="3_on.png" data-active="on" onclick="activate_togle(this)">
<img alt="" src="img/4_off.png" class="pic" data-toggle="4_on.png" data-active="on" onclick="activate_togle(this)">
<img alt="" src="img/5_off.png" class="pic" data-toggle="5_on.png" data-active="on" onclick="activate_togle(this)">


<script>
function activate_toggle(obj){
 let output_toggle=$(obj).data('toggle');
 if($(obj).data('active')=='on'){
   var num = output_toggle.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  let change_toggle=num+'_off.png';
    $(obj).data('toggle',change_toggle);
    $(obj).data('active','off');
 }else{
   var num = output_toggle.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
   let change_toggle=num+'_on.png';
    $(obj).data('toggle',change_toggle);
   $(obj).data('active','on');
 }
 $(obj).attr('src','img/'+output_toggle);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! The image changes to on when clicked, but there is no response when clicked again. Can you tell me how to change the image when you click and then change it back to the original image (_off) when you click again?

Comment: i have just update the script , will you please try that again.